# C program crashes when executed

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C but today when I compiled my program it crashes when executed.

I want my program to input three strings, match every letter of those strings with an indexed number, add those numbers to each other, and output those numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
   int i, j;

   int c = 0; 
   int e = 0; 
   int d = 0;

   char wrd1[4];
   char wrd2[4];
   char wrd3[4];

   char az[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

   printf("Enter The words ");

   printf("\n");

   scanf("%s", &wrd1);

   printf("\n");

   scanf("%s", &wrd2);

   printf("\n");

   scanf("%s", &wrd3);

   int n = sizeof(wrd1) / sizeof(char);

   int m = sizeof(wrd2) / sizeof(char);

   int o = sizeof(wrd3) / sizeof(char);

   for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
      {
         if (az[i] = wrd1[j])
         {
            c = c + i;
         }
      }
   }

   for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j <= m; j++)
      {
         if (az[i] = wrd2[j])
         {
            d = d + i;
         }
      }
   }

   for (i = 0; i <= 25; i++)
   {
      for (j = 0; j <= o; j++)
      {
         if (az[i] = wrd3[j])
         {
            e = e + i;
         }
      }
   }

   printf(c);
   printf(d);
   printf(e);

}
```

Comment: Are you compiling with warnings turned on? That will reveal a lot of bugs.

Comment: Instead of dumping your entire program here, reduce your program to the simplest code that still crashes, then make that your question.

Comment: Not testing the return value from scanf is a sure recipe for surprises!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Code questions here should include **minimal** reproducers -- with all code not absolutely required to reproduce the problem removed. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `char wrd1[4]` only allows you to enter a three letter word. The fourth element of the array is needed for the null terminator.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible your code has multiple problems, but as a minimum you have a problem here (in multiple locations)

```
for (j = 0; j <= n; j++)
```

because of the `<=` you are allowing the function to read beyond the array bounds here (inside your loop)

```
if (az[i] = wrd3[j])
```

Reading array elements outisde the bounds of an array is undefined behaviour and the likely source of your crash (although your code may have other errors also).

Changing your loop to

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
               ^
               ^
```

ensures you do not overstep the array bounds.

Finally, in the line

```
if (az[i] = wrd3[j])
```

you likely meant to use `==` as what you have currently is assignment, **not** comparison. This won't cause a crash but is a bug unless you **are** trying to assign to `az[i]`.

Comment: And `m`, `n`, and `o` will always be 4 by definition.

Comment: i modified my code like you said but visual studio gave me this"Exception thrown at 0x0FC44B2A (ucrtbased.dll) in ConsoleApplication7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000659."

Comment: @Med Have you also changed the `printf` calls like the other answer suggests?

Comment: Yes i did that ??????????!

Comment: @Med and what strings are you inputting from the console that are read into your arrays? Are they more than 3 characters long?

Comment: no !! did you test the code in your machine ??

Answer (score 2):

To print the value of `c` you should not use `printf(c);`, but something like `printf("%d\n", c);` .